# Loop conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, conditional-statements

I am still learning C# and i have a quick question in regards to loop conditions. Ill will try to explain my question a clearly as possible, so i apologize ahead of time if i confuse anyone. So lets say i have a number that is in the form of a double that was inputted from a user(I picked a double because i use them mostly but this is not all inclusive, meaning it can be a decimal, or a integer as well). Now in my loop i want to have the condition set to ensure the number is not a character (I.E. the user enters the letter instead of a number.), so that when this happens a messagebox will appear saying to enter numbers only. I only ask this because i do not know how to code this and every time i run the program the whole program stops because the input was in the incorrect format. How can i code my loop to verify the input is actually numbers and not letters? I would like to have a messagebox popup saying "Enter numbers only please". I know how to do everything else except coding this part. I have tried god knows how many times to ask this question on the internet and in these forms, but i dont ever get a clear answer. 
For those that need to see some kind of code to get a better understanding it is as follows (FYI i am using windows forms):

```
        double amnt = Convert.ToDouble(txtAMNT.Text);
        string Amount=txtAMNT.Text;
        double rate = Convert.ToDouble(txtRATE.Text);
        string Rate = txtRATE.Text;
        double time = Convert.ToDouble(txtTIME.Text);
        string Time=txtTIME.Text;
        double monthpay;
        double totalinterest;
        double realrate = (rate / 12)/100;

        if ((Amount == "")||(Rate == "")||(Time==""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill all boxes with numbers");
        }
        else if (!(Rate == "."))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the rate with a decimal sign ' . ' .");
        }
        else if (Amount == ",")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the Amount without Commas ' , '");
        }
        else if ((Time == ",") || (Time == "."))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the Duration in Months with out any decimals or commas.");
        }
        else
        {
            monthpay = amnt * realrate / (1 - Math.Pow(1 + realrate, -time));
            totalinterest = time * monthpay - amnt;
            mtbMonPay.Text = monthpay.ToString("c");
            mtbTotalInterest.Text = totalinterest.ToString("c");


        }
```

Comment: What makes you think that your question is about loops? Your question is *not* about loops, it's about receiving and parsing user input. It doesn't matter that your condition happens to be a loop condition; your immediate problem is getting the condition (and the code leading up to it) to work correctly. (Btw. you might get more / better answers if you didn't declare your question's main topic incorrectly. Just a suggestion. :-)

Comment: You should research into `TryParse` methods

Comment: Just don't use `TextBox`.

Comment: @Sayse - thank man that helped, i had to recode a lot but it works! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is use TryParse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx

TryParse returns a bool that tells you if the conversion failed, and if it was successful, the out value will have the result you're looking for. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You really should do some research on how to parse user input in .Net. Nevertheless, something simple you could do is the following:

```
static bool ParseField(string fieldName, string fieldValueText, out double fieldValue)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValueText)) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Please provide an input value for '{0}'.", fieldName));
        return false;
    }
    else if (!double.TryParse(fieldValueText, out fieldValue))  
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid floating point value. Please provide a valid floating point input value for '{1}'.", fieldValueText, fieldName));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

which could be used in something like:

```
bool GetInputs(out double amnt, out double rate, out double time)
{
    if (ParseField("Amount", txtAMNT.Text, out amnt) &&
        ParseField("Rate", txtRATE.Text, out rate) &&
        ParseField("Time", txtTIME.Text, out time))
    {
        // Perform additional checks on individual values if needed.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```